# set proxy through windows command line without login parameters

Tags: cmd, proxy

I have some proxy applications like Ultra-surf or Tor-browser. I can set their proxy in browsers or on other applications. For example for Tor, I can set socks: to "127.0.0.1:9150" in any application.

but I want to using this proxy for CMD.

I saw these answers

`netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=localhost:9090" bypass-list="localhost"`

Or

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port`

I opend a CMD as an Administrato, and then I tried these commands. After each one, I tested 3 sites: "google.com" and "facebook.com" and "youtu.be". But noting was changed. "google.com" always works and "facebook.com and youtu.be" do not work. Also, It does not make difference if my proxy apllication be open or not. 
Anyone knows how can I set this kind of proxy for CMD?

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:1080

netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=127.0.0.1:9150" bypass-list="127.0.0.1"

netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=localhost:9150" bypass-list="localhost"

netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http=127.0.0.1:1080" bypass-list="127.0.0.1"

netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="https=127.0.0.1:1080" bypass-list="127.0.0.1"

set HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:1080

set HTTPs_PROXY=127.0.0.1:1080

set HTTP_PROXY=@127.0.0.1:1080

set HTTPs_PROXY=@127.0.0.1:1080

set HTTP_PROXY=:@127.0.0.1:1080

set HTTPs_PROXY=:@127.0.0.1:1080
```

The ping response always is:

For not sensored site:

```
C:\>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.18.142] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 time=198ms TTL=51
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 time=94ms TTL=51
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 time=95ms TTL=51
Reply from 172.217.18.142: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=51

Ping statistics for 172.217.18.142:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 94ms, Maximum = 198ms, Average = 122ms
```

For sensored sites:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping youtu.be
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping facebook.com

Pinging facebook.com [10.10.34.35] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.10.34.35:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```